# Collections is showing but documents is not showing in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean

I am new in MEAN web app and I downloaded the dummy project in MEAN, there

sign-up and login. mongoDB connected successfully and I created a collection

**user**.sign-up and login functionality working well.everything is OK. But I am

confuse about user collection documents. When I sign up definitely data goes to the user collection because login done successfully but when I use this command

```
                           db.collection.find()
```

Nothing result show I created so many account and using them login successfully

And if I use wrong username or password then login not allowed. Please tell me

where is store data in mongoDB. bellow

my **app.js** file

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var api = require('./routes/api');
var users = require('./routes/users');

// database connectivity
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/ditroapp');
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('mongo connection error', err);
});

db.once('open', function () {
  console.log('mongo connected.');
});

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/api', api);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Comment: are you activating mongo's shell properly? and you need to switch to right DB as well.

Comment: @GandalftheWhite:-when I insert data using command prompt then these data show using command db.user.find() but data is inserted using signup form is not showing

Comment: Then there must be some problem with your insertion. Check the name of the collection etc. and it is difficult to figure out your problem unless you dig deep into your own code. We don't know what actually you are doing.

Comment: Where is the code via which insertion is being done?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if i have understood your question.
In the mongoshell if you want to use a certain db you have to run the command
"use name_db" where name_db is the name of the db you created. After that you can show the collections in the selected db with the command "show collections".
After that you can find all the document in a collection with the command
db.name_collection.find() where nome_collection if the name of the collection you want to retrieve data

Comment: I did all step but problem is same, and i create the connection in app.js files and this database showing  show dbs

Comment: maybe the problem is in the javascript code that doesn't insert the data in the db correctly

Comment: no data is inserted successfully becuase after sign up then i can login otherwise login is not allowed

Comment: are you sure in the mongoshell have selected the correctd db. In the app.js the name of the db is ditroapp. before executing a find() you have to selected first the db via the command use ditroapp